# "attempt to index global 'f' (a function value)" when trying to attach a function to the result of loadfile

Tags: lua

The code says it all:

```
#tryModA.lua:
f,err=loadfile("tryModB.lua")
if not f then
    print("F is nil!!! Err:"..err)
else
    f.fn=function (x)
        print("x="..x)
    end
    f()
end
```

And here is the loaded file:

```
#tryModB.lua:
fn("hello")
```

Error:

```
lua: tryModA.lua:7: attempt to index global 'f' (a function value)
stack traceback:
    tryModA.lua:7: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

**Question**: why does it happen ?

Isn't it true that `loadfile()` returns a function object and I can attach another function to it? PS. I come from a JavaScript programming background where it has prototype-based objects. I assume Lua has the same prototype based objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua, `loadfile()` returns a function (not a function object) and functions can only be called. "Attaching" whatever to a function like you are trying is not possible.

Now, Lua tables are completely different story and the prototype-based concepts from JavaScript probably apply to them (I'm not very familiar with JS). The simplest way to make your code work at this point is to make `fn` global i.e. replace `f.fn = function...` with `fn = function...` although this might not be what you want.